# DD WRT in Repeater mode but no DHCP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp, dd-wrt

I have DD WRT on my landlords router and its set up to be a repeater, it gets its WIFI from their house (I do not have access to the main network, just the WiFi that DD WRT thing gives me), the problem is I think that the DD WRT is not configured to have a DHCP server. My issue is that I am connected with a cable to it and have internet, but no one else can connect and get an IP while I'm on it.

Can I run a DHCP server on my PC and have it rebroadcast the singnal through my wireless USB card?

Comment: How does your computer get an IP if there's no DHCP? Can you not just turn on DHCP on the DD-WRT router?

Comment: I haven't a clue how it gets an IP. It does, I am online through the DD-WRT now on my PC. I have no access to the DD-WRT settings (don't have the password, landlords have their guy who gets paid 40 bucks per visit, and he has been here today, and screwed this up). As I see it, only one person at a time can have Internet connection through this DD-WRT device, others connect, but can't acess internet. Here is the screenshot of what I can acess. [link] http://imgur.com/6Y1MU4y @qasdfdsaq

Comment: so, ({house}---wire---{ddwrt device}:::wireless:::) is broken, but ({house}---wire---{ddwrt device}---wire---pc) works?

Comment: @Yorik its house ---wire--- some TP LINK ---wireless--- DD-WRT ---wire--- My PC and yes that one works, but the DD-WRT ---wireless-- laptop doesnt. And I've just connected another laptop with a cable while my main PC is online and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you running Windows? If so do `ipconfig /all` in a cmd prompt. Your screenshot is helpful. It shows DHCP is off, but nothing preventing other computers from connecting. It is operating in full router mode. I suspect simply replicating an appropriate static IP setting from your computer on another would work

Comment: @qasdfsaq I have set static IP addresses on two diffetent machines and it works. Also without imputing DNS addresses web browsing didn't work. Now I would still like to share the connection from my PC via wireless and have done so with remote router program but the speeds are really low and it disconnects my main PC when the connected device starts using the connection.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the DD-WRT device is configured as a bridge rather than a repeater. The simplest solution would be to purchase a wireless access point and plug it into the wireless bridge.

Answer (score -1):

You have two issues:

- If DD-WRT is acting as a repeater, then it doesn't have an IP - it's just taking traffic in one end and spitting it back out the other like a switch or an Ethernet cable.
- A cable modem will respond to one and only one device that appears on its Ethernet port - typically the first one.  If you try to connect a switch to a cable modem, it will only talk to the first device that talks to it.  If you want to share your cable modem's Internet among multiple systems, that one device needs to be a router.

If your PC can get  Internet via the cable modem which it sounds like it already does, basically your solution is to turn the PC into a router.  If this PC is running Windows, the Internet Connection Sharing feature pretty much does this and will take care of DHCP for you as well.

Routers require two network interfaces - one for the cable modem or WAN, and the other for your LAN.  The problem with using your wireless USB as the "LAN" side is that it has to work like an AP if you want more than one system to connect to it.  AP mode is probably not supported by your hardware.

But you could get a USB-to-Ethernet adapter, and a second wireless router.  Set up Internet Connection Sharing on the adapter, and disable DHCP on the second wireless router (because Internet Connection Sharing will provide the DHCP on the PC) and connect a LAN port of your second wireless router (NOT the WAN or Internet port) to the USB-to-Ethernet adapter and it will work.

Comment: The screenshot shows it **does** have two interfaces.

Comment: Not talking about the router, the PC.

Comment: @LawrenceC hello. I have  configured my PC to a static IP and set the gateway and Skype connected but couldn't browse the web so I put the DNS addresses from open DNS (Google) and it works. I have done the same on the laptop and those two devices can be online at the same time now. What is the cause of this?

Comment: @user22975: You already know the cause of this. The cause is the router doesn't have DHCP so you have to assign addresses manually.